# QT app flickers after psplash-systemd finishes

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, splash-screen, framebuffer, eglfs

I have a linux system created in Yocto running on Raspberry Pi CM4 and I am using psplash utility for splashscreen. During early stage of boot I also launch my qt app (before psplash-systemd is finished) and I am rendering the app on screen by using only framebuffer and eglfs. The issue I am having is that after psplash-systemd does finish it closes the framebuffer which is causing my qt app to flicker screen once. Is there any way to prevent this ? I tried to play with eglfs to stop this from happening and noticed that if I am not using the

QT_QPA_EGLFS_ALWAYS_SET_MODE=1
QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_ATOMIC=1

the issue is not happening but I have this [issue](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=252614) with that configuration.